# Set text inside @html.Textareafor

Tags: html, asp.net, razor

I am using asp.net core razor engine.  I am trying to set text inside of my text area.  I looked on stack and followed previous answers, but nothing seems to be working.
 Here is my code

```
<h1>@TempData["quote"]</h1>// this prints out the correct value
@model login.Models.Quotes
<h1>Edit Your Quote</h1>
@using(Html.BeginForm("EditQuote","Home"))
{
    <p>
        <label>Your Quote</label>
        @Html.TextAreaFor(d=>d.quotes, new { @Value = @TempData["quote"]})
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(d => d.quotes)
    </p>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Edit my quote!"/>
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't use attributes to set the value in the *view* - you set the value in the *controller* through the *model* property and bind that property to the text box.

In your controller:

```
model.quotes = TempData["quote"];
```

In your view:

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(model=>model.quotes)
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like maybe your lamda expression is not being evaluated properly.
Try:

```
  @Html.TextAreaFor(d => d.quotes, new { @Value = @TempData["quote"]})
```